# 3 x 3 Grid Square Problem

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

For a question that I need to answer, we have to show that there is **only one** arrangement for which, in a 3 x 3 grid in which the numbers from 1 to 9 are placed and 5 is the centre number, the sum of the 4 numbers in every 2 x 2 grid found within the 3 x 3 grid all add up to the same number. I have found the answer, which is a grid with the numbers as follows:

```
1  8  3

6  5  4

7  2  9
```

I don't know why this is the only option (except for rotations and reflections). Does anyone know why this is true?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. This question seems to be a Mathematics homework and not related to puzzles directly. Please have a look at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this has a 'clever' solution exploiting e.g. symmetries, and then it's probably on-topic: [Math puzzles are on topic, math problems are not](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/11110)

Comment: The same question is posted at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594097/3-x-3-grid-square), with quite an extensive answer.